# How to update List<string> column using Mapper.UpdateAsync in Cassandra?

Tags: c#, cassandra, nosql

I am a newbie to Cassandra and my current project called for me to create a table with the following columns:

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
connections list<text>,
username text
```

I am using Cassandra's IMapper interface to handle my CRUD operations.  While I found documentation that describes how to use the Mapping component for basic operations here:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/mapperComponent.html

I could not find documentation that outlines how to add and remove items from the List column for a specific record using the Mapper component.  I tried to retrieve the record from the database, update the entity and save the changes to the record but the record is not updated in the database.  It remains the same after the Update.  However, the insert operation works and it mirrors the entity down to the object in the list.

```
User user = await _mapper.SingleAsync<T>("where Name = " + name);
user.Addresses = user.Addresses.Concat(new string[] { address });
await _mapper.UpdateAsync<T>(user);
```

How should this scenario be handled in Cassandra?

Comment: How did you get on with the answers provided below, @user1790300?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [plus (+) and minus (-) CQL operators](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#lists) to append / prepend or remove items from a list.

In your case it would be:

```
// When using parameters, use query markers (?) instead of 
// hardcoded stringified values
User user = await _mapper.SingleAsync<User>("where id = ?", id);
await _mapper.UpdateAsync<T>(
    "SET connections = connections + ? WHERE id = ?", newConnections, id");
```

Note that append and prepend operations are not idempotent by nature. So in particular, if one of these operation timeout, then retrying the operation is not safe and it may (or may not) lead to appending/prepending the value twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order for this to work and be efficient you may need several things:

- partial update

It is atomic and doesn't require you to fetch the record first. Also, specifying only the fields you want to update avoids passing unnecessary load on the wire and relieves the pressure on the compactor.

- use CqlOperator.Append/CqlOperator.Prepend/CqlOperator.SubstractAssign

Which allow you to specify only the collection items you want to add/remove.

Both of these optimizations are available via the `Table` API, not sure about the `Mapper`.